# RecyclerView has an instance for each item of a list

Tags: android

I have a fragment which shows a list of tv show episodes , swiping left or right will switch to the next or previous episode(this is done by `ViewPager`), then I created a horizontal `RecyclerView` to show the list of the episodes in a horizontal scroll bar.

Now I have 2 problems

**Problem 1**
For example I selected episode 9, now episode 9 is highlighted in the `RecyclerView` Scroll bar then I scroll until I reach 14, 15, 17 (this is the last scroll state of 9) then I click on 14 it gets highlighted but the scroll resets to 1 (which is not what I want) , now I scroll back and I see 14 is highlighted , now when I scroll back to 9 and tap on it , the scroll state of 9 goes to the last state that I scrolled to 15 and clicked on it. Please check this [**video**](https://youtu.be/aQIN-j_Peww)

**Problem 2**
For example I selected 2 now I tap on 3, it switches to 3 but the highlight is still on 2 I have to click again on 3 to get it highlighted. please take a look at this [**video**](https://youtu.be/m8IIxjh4g9E)

**I think this is all caused by the fact that each episode or I should say each page of `ViewPager` has its own instance of the `RecyclerView`. correct me if I'm wrong**

But what I want is a single instance of `RecyclerView` to be available for all episodes.

**How can I Fix that?**

**Hint**
RecyclerView Adapter is set inside the **fragment**, transfering the index of the clicked item (episode) from the adapter to the fragment via `onItemClick` interface from the adapter. From inside the fragment I use another interface `sendText(int position);` to tranfer the index of the clicked item to the **Activity** so that I can set ViewPager `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position,false);`

**RecyclerView Adapter**

```
public class PlanetAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlanetAdapter.PlanetViewHolder> {


    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(String item);
    }
    private static int lastClickedPosition = -1;
    private int selectedItem;

    private ArrayList<String> episodeslist;
    private OnItemClickListener listener;


    SharedPreferences getPref1x1 = getContext().getSharedPreferences("PlanetAdapter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int pos1x1 = getPref1x1.getInt("position",0);

    int selectedPosition=pos1x1;


    public PlanetAdapter(ArrayList<String> episodeslist, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.episodeslist = episodeslist;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public PlanetAdapter.PlanetViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.planet_row, parent,false);
        PlanetViewHolder vh=new PlanetViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PlanetAdapter.PlanetViewHolder vh, int position) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) vh.itemView;
        tv.setText(episodeslist.get(position));
        tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.bg, 0, 0, 0);

        vh.bind(episodeslist.get(position), listener);


        //if(selectedPosition==position)
        //    vh.itemView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLight));
        //else
        //    vh.itemView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

        vh.itemView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLight));

        if (selectedPosition == position) {
            vh.itemView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        }



        //holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.planetimage);
        //vh.text.setText(episodeslist.get(position).toString());
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return episodeslist.size();
    }


    public class PlanetViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        protected TextView text;
        public PlanetViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_id);
        }
        public void bind(final String item, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getPosition();

                    int previousItem = selectedPosition;
                    selectedPosition = position;

                    notifyItemChanged(previousItem);
                    notifyItemChanged(position);

                    //selectedPosition=position;
                    //notifyDataSetChanged();




                    SharedPreferences setPref = v.getContext().getSharedPreferences("PlanetAdapter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    setPref.edit().putInt("position", position).apply ();



                     listener.onItemClick(item);
                    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You have clicked " + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You have clicked " + ((TextView) itemView).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**The Fragment**

```
public class TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment extends Fragment {

    TextClicked mCallback;

    public interface TextClicked{
        void sendText(int position);
    }

// other code here

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.episode_details, container, false);
    }

@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (TextClicked) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement TextClicked");
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


// other code here

// getting episodeslist
        mEpisodesList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.episodesLIST);
        ArrayList<String> episodeslist = new ArrayList<String>(mEpisodes.size()); //set initialize capacity as it's know, some negligible performance related reason

        for(TvShowEpisode e : mEpisodes){
            episodeslist.add(e.mEpisode);
        }


        // Setting LinearLayoutManager
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext.getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        //mEpisodesList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
        mEpisodesList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        // Setting RecyclerView Adapter
        mEpisodesList.setAdapter(new PlanetAdapter(episodeslist, new PlanetAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override public void onItemClick(String item) {
                SharedPreferences getPref = getActivity ().getSharedPreferences("PlanetAdapter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                int pos = getPref.getInt("position",0);
                mCallback.sendText(pos);
            }
        }));


// other code here

}

@Override
    public void onDetach() {
        mCallback = null; // => avoid leaking, thanks @Deepscorn
        super.onDetach();
    }

// other code here

}
```

**The activity**

```
public class TvShowEpisodeDetails extends MizActivity implements TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment.TextClicked{

    private static final String SHOW_ID = "showId";

    private ArrayList<TvShowEpisode> mEpisodes = new ArrayList<TvShowEpisode>();
    private int mSeason, mEpisode;
    private String mShowId, mShowTitle;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes mDatabaseHelper;
    private Bus mBus;

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResource() {
        return R.layout.viewpager_with_toolbar_overlay;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mBus = MizuuApplication.getBus();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set theme
        setTheme(R.style.Mizuu_Theme_NoBackground);

        ViewUtils.setupWindowFlagsForStatusbarOverlay(getWindow(), true);

        ViewUtils.setProperToolbarSize(this, mToolbar);

        mShowId = getIntent().getExtras().getString(SHOW_ID);
        mSeason = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("season");
        mEpisode = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("episode");

        mDatabaseHelper = MizuuApplication.getTvEpisodeDbAdapter();

        Cursor cursor = mDatabaseHelper.getEpisodes(mShowId);
        try {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                mEpisodes.add(new TvShowEpisode(this, mShowId,
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_TITLE)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_PLOT)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_SEASON)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_AIRDATE)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_DIRECTOR)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_WRITER)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_GUESTSTARS)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_RATING)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_HAS_WATCHED)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_FAVOURITE))
                        ));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }

        mShowTitle = MizuuApplication.getTvDbAdapter().getShowTitle(mShowId);
        setTitle(mShowTitle);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.awesomepager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new TvShowEpisodeDetailsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                ViewUtils.updateToolbarBackground(TvShowEpisodeDetails.this, mToolbar, 0, mEpisodes.get(position).getTitle(), Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab", 0));
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < mEpisodes.size(); i++) {
                if (mEpisodes.get(i).getSeason().equals(MizLib.addIndexZero(mSeason)) && mEpisodes.get(i).getEpisode().equals(MizLib.addIndexZero(mEpisode))) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                    SharedPreferences setPref1x1 = getContext().getSharedPreferences("PlanetAdapter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    setPref1x1.edit().putInt("position", i).apply ();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onScrollChanged(TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment.BusToolbarColorObject object) {
        ViewUtils.updateToolbarBackground(this, mToolbar, object.getAlpha(),
                mEpisodes.get(mViewPager.getCurrentItem()).getTitle(), object.getToolbarColor());
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mBus.register(this);
        ViewUtils.updateToolbarBackground(this, mToolbar, 0, mShowTitle, Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        mBus.unregister(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("tab", mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
    }


    @Override
    public void sendText(int position) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position,false);
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Item Clicked " + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    private class TvShowEpisodeDetailsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public TvShowEpisodeDetailsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override  
        public Fragment getItem(int index) {
            return TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment.newInstance(mShowId, Integer.parseInt(mEpisodes.get(index).getSeason()), Integer.parseInt(mEpisodes.get(index).getEpisode()));
        }  

        @Override  
        public int getCount() {  
            return mEpisodes.size();
        }
    }
    
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just saved the position of the selected item but not the state of all the items in the list i.e whether they are selected or unselected.
Recycler View recycles the views when scrolled.
So, you just need to use ArrayList of PlanelModel instead of ArrayList of String as shared below which has a variable called "isPlanetSelected" to save state of the item.

```
public class PlanetModel {
    private String planetName;
    private boolean isPlanetSelected;

    public String getPlanetName() {
        return planetName;
    }

    public void setPlanetName(String planetName) {
        this.planetName = planetName;
    }

    public boolean isPlanetSelected() {
        return isPlanetSelected;
    }

    public void setPlanetSelected(boolean planetSelected) {
        isPlanetSelected = planetSelected;
    }
}
```

Make following changes in your PlanetAdapter class:

ArrayList of PlanetModel instead of String:

```
private ArrayList<PlanetModel> episodeslist;
```

In onBindViewHolder set name of the episode as:

```
tv.setText(episodeslist.get(position).getPlanetName());
```

In onBindViewHolder set selected state of the view:

```
    if (episodeslist.get(position).isPlanetSelected()) {
        vh.itemView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    }else{
        vh.itemView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLight));
    }
```

Also, update the isPlanetSelected for that particular index

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    for (int i=0; i<mEpisodes.length; i++)
    {
        mEpisodes.get(i).setIsPlanetSelected(false);
    }
    mEpisodes.get(position).setIsPlanetSelected(true);
    //notify your recycler views adaper

    }
});
```

mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
episodeslist.get(position).setPlanetSelected(true)
}
});

Don't forget to set planet selected false wen it is unselected

```
episodeslist.get(position).setPlanetSelected(false)
```

Both your issues will be resolved with above approach.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much , I will try it right now

Comment: Is there a way not to change the Arraylist type to PlanelModel , Because origionally the mEpisode is of type String , I have a lot of things to change to PlanelModel type , is there an alternate route, please fovgive for that.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to refactor the type of the ArrayList, you will have to update the type everywhere manually. You can just find the occurences of ArrayList<String> and replace it with ArrayList<PlanetModel> where required replace mEpisode.get() with mEpisode.get().getPlanetName()

Comment: One more question please where should I put `episodeslist.get(position).setPlanetSelected(false)` is that suppose to go inside `onBindViewHolder` too ?

Comment: I have updated the setOnPageChangeListener please check

Comment: Thank you so much , but believe me I have to change  a lot of things , that I can't wrap my mind around it , please look at this [screenshot](https://imgur.com/H48IIYK) , this is just the tip of the iceberg , my project is huge , can I share the source code with you?

Comment: Yes, please share it.

Comment: if you can help me out I would be forever grateful

Comment: Hi, are you there @RupinderKaur

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233991/discussion-between-cyberpunk-and-rupinder-kaur).