# Coverting a String to a model type

Tags: java, string

I have an Arraylist of String type like this `ArrayList<String> episodeslist;`, I use the Arraylist for a RecyclerView Adapter , but the I had to convert the String type to PlanetModel type , Originally the Arraylist is defined insdie a fragment as follows:

```java
ArrayList<String> episodeslist = new ArrayList<String>(mEpisodes.size());

for (TvShowEpisode e : mEpisodes) {
    episodeslist.add(e.mEpisode);
}
```

when I change

```java
ArrayList<String> episodeslist = new ArrayList<String>(mEpisodes.size());
```

To

```java
ArrayList<PlanetModel> episodeslist = new ArrayList<PlanetModel>(mEpisodes.size());
```

I also have to convert the `mEpisode` which is also of Sting type to PlanetModel as well , how can I do that? I'm asking this because the project is huge , `mEpisode` has so many usages , that is not applicable to change every instance of `mEpisode` to `PlanetModel` , so I'm looking for a solution.

**Hint:**
I'm doing this because of [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68049239/16179902)

**PlanetModel**

```java
public class PlanetModel {
    private String planetName;
    private boolean isPlanetSelected;

    public String getPlanetName() {
        return planetName;
    }

    public void setPlanetName(String planetName) {
        this.planetName = planetName;
    }

    public boolean isPlanetSelected() {
        return isPlanetSelected;
    }

    public void setPlanetSelected(boolean planetSelected) {
        isPlanetSelected = planetSelected;
    }

    public int compareToIgnoreCase(PlanetModel string) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is the question? What issue are you facing and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks, mEpisode is a String , it is inside the Arraylist mEpisodes , but in my recyclerview adapter , I need to change the the String to PlanetModel, because I got a problem with single selection of recyclerview, if you follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68048875/recyclerview-has-an-instance-for-each-item-of-a-list/68049239#68049239) , you will see what I'm talking about

Comment: I tried to change the ArrayList<String> to ArrayList<PlanetModel> , I ended up getting error saying `mEpisode is String cannot be converted to PlanetModel`

Comment: I want to know how to resolve this error, the `mEpisode is String cannot be converted to PlanetModel` , hence I want to know if there is a way to change mEpisode String to PlanetModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you:

```
ArrayList<PlanetModel> episodeslist = mEpisodes.stream().map(s -> new PlanetModel(s)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

I think you better add a constructor to your PlanetModel class so you can do it in one line.

update:
if you are using 1.8-, try this:

```
    ArrayList<String> mEpisodes = new ArrayList<String>();
    ...
    ArrayList<PlanetModel> episodeslist = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String s : mEpisodes){
        PlanetModel model = new PlanetModel();
        model.setPlanetName(s);
        episodeslist.add(model);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I'm not mistaken stream  is available in java 1.8, but I'm using 1.7

Comment: @cyberpunk create an empty arraylist of PlanetModel, then iterate through the episodeslist and in every iteration create a PlanetModel instance and add it to the arraylist.

Comment: Well, I'm not very good at java, can you help me achieve that , please?

Comment: Thanks , but in this `for(String s : mEpisodes){` are you refering to `mEpisode` or `mEpisodes`  , becuase I had issues with `mEpisode` after converting to PlanetModel ?

Comment: because I only need need the mEpisode from  mEpisodes , because mEpisodes has other elemets beside mEpisode

Comment: Because now mEpiosde is still giving me problem

Comment: @cyberpunk try removing line 284 because I think it shadows the variable you already defined in this scope, then change the 296 to `episodesList.add(new PlanetModel(e.mEpisode);` ,also remove lines from 286 to 290, cuz you are doing the same thing on lines 295 to 297.

Comment: thank you I did that but the [**error**](https://imgur.com/JTQh6Yn) is still there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234025/discussion-between-cyberpunk-and-roophie).